# Single Query for two table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Update table_1 set value="0" where key="1";
update table_2 set status="confirmed" where id="1"
```

there is nothing common in both table but wanted to execute both at the same time by a single query instead of above two separate query.

Comment: Why? Is there an issue with speed?

Comment: Yeah, I aggree with imulsion, is there an issue?

Comment: If you need the two updates to be executed atomically (i.e., if one fails they both fail), use a **transaction** (`BEGIN` and `COMMIT` statements, Google it). Otherwise, just run two `UPDATE`s, what's the problem

Comment: then you need a stored proc

Comment: @Nadeem_MK Thanks for your time. I would learn about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not execute update statement for two tables, you will need to have two statements.
If you need to be sure that both tables were updated, you should use transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
-- update statements
COMMIT;
```